# Где хранить состояние Redux?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux

У меня есть приложение и подключенный редакс
Экшены и редюсеры настроены

Всё работает как надо, но я хочу чтобы состояние сохранялось при перезагрузке страницы.

Куда обычно сохраняют состояние Redux приложения?
Если записать в localStorage, то где именно это делать? (В экшенах, редюсерах, или где?)

Comment: Сохранять в localStorage при изменении свойств, которые хотите хранить в localStorage. Таким образом в LS всегда будет актуальное состояние
- помните об ограничении размера LS
- не забываете удалять пустые свойства

Comment: после перезагрузки ты береш состояние то есть initialState  из localStorage , логичнее всего в редюсерах

Answer (score 1):

**Все зависит от ваших потребностей:**

1. Если хотите чтобы на разных браузерах/устройствах/... сохранялось одно и то же состояние, то вам обязательно нужно хранить это на сервере и запрашивать после/во время авторизации
   В этом случае инициализировать сохраненное состояние после выполнения асинхронного запроса через экшены
2. Если вам достаточно чтобы хранение было привязано чисто к браузеру, то вам достаточно будет использовать localStorage как уже отмечали в комментариях к вашему вопросу
   В этом случае самый лучший вариант действительно инициализировать в редьюсере (запихивая это прямо в initialState редьюсера)